# why the print result is "favicon.ico" in web.py

Tags: python, web, web.py

I have a question about web.py.

The following is the example code from web.py tutorial. I added a print row into the code as `print name`. run `python test.py`, and then open http://0.0.0.0:8080/baby in the brower, you will see "hello baby" in the html page. However, in the terminal, you will see the print result is "favicon.ico".

I know favicon.ico, but I am pretty confused about why it doesn't print "baby".

Can someone explain this for me? Thanks to everybody~

```
import web

urls = (
'/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        print name
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you Selcuk, your answer is perfect~!

Answer (score 1):

Your web browser also requests favicon.ico automatically to show a small icon in your browser tab, ie:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/favicon.ico
```

in which case `name` is equal to `"favicon.ico"`